# Moving from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 to 2.0.0.M7 - dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:jar is missing

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social

I'm trying to upgrade my application from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 to 2.0.0.M7

After upgrading my Maven application I ran into the following errors:

[image]

For example the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

shows the following error:

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:jar is missing.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency management and auto-configuration for Spring Social was [removed from Spring Boot in 2.0 M7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M7-Release-Notes#spring-social). The longer-term plan is for it to move into Spring Social itself but that has yet to happen.